# Consulting an array VS consulting a Database to validate Data

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

I'm building an International Website. Users can choose their country when they sign-up from a `<select></select>` field in a form.

Assuming someone didn't use the form to send the data to the processing page where I validate the data, what is better to do to check if the country is valid, to consult an array or a database of countries? (All the countries in the world)

Programming language: PHP 5.3.5

Database: MySQL 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to include all the countries (there are ~196 countries in the world), using a database table to store and update the data related to the countries would be a conventional and fine design choice. It will also be easier to maintain the country information this way.

Answer (score 2):

Since the country list is pretty static stuff, I think that using an array could be the best choice.

Are you going to support all the countries of the world or just a subset? In any case just remember to unset your array when not needed anymore, just to free up memory.

On the other side a database could add an easy way to achieve more complete control over the country list (think about adding a specific order or sort, or whatever) using SQL

Comment: I'm supporting all the countries in the World.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many countries you support.
If you have all the countries, I would go with the database approach. Seems more maintainable. Can be updated through external apps, unlike the hardcoded array which only you can update by changing the code.

Also, by using a database, you decouple the data from the code. This way you don't have to change and compile your code every time you add a country.

I'd use the array only for about 20 countries.